# How can we locate the value displaying in a p tag in Selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium WebDriver I am trying to locate some value `$2,772 /month` displaying in a `p` tag. I have tried the below, but while running the test I am getting following error :

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='calculatedresult']//div[@class='_3Kmts']//div[@class='ant-row _2kHnl']//div[@class='z-k7K ant-col-xs-24']//p[@class='_3TRls _2fRgA']"}
> (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)

Selenium version: `selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-6`

```
WebElement resultElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='calculatedresult']//div[@class='_3Kmts']//div[@class='ant-row _2kHnl']//div[@class='z-k7K ant-col-xs-24']//p[@class='_3TRls _2fRgA']"));
String resultText = resultElement.getText();
System.out.println("Amount:"+resultText);
```

```html
<div class="XE8MI" id="calculatedresult">
  <div class="_3Kmts">
    <div class="ant-row _2kHnl">
      <div class="ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-24 ant-col-md-12">
        <p class="_3TRls _145-y">
          <!-- react-text: 559 -->How much will you
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 560 -->&nbsp;
          <!-- /react-text --><span class="_2O2nq">pay each month?</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="z-k7K ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-24 ant-col-md-12">
        <p class="_3TRls _1QZuL">
          <!-- react-text: 564 -->Your
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 565 -->&nbsp;
          <!-- /react-text --><span class="_34T3z">estimated repayments</span>
          <!-- react-text: 567 -->
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 568 -->could be
          <!-- /react-text -->
        </p>
        <p class="_3TRls _2fRgA">
          <!-- react-text: 570 -->$
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 571 -->2,772
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 572 -->&nbsp;
          <!-- /react-text --><span class="_3VTnt"><!-- react-text: 574 -->/ month<!-- /react-text --><sup>*</sup></span></p>
        <p class="_3TRls _2w2vj">
          <!-- react-text: 577 -->At an interest rate of
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 578 -->2.00
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 579 -->% over
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 580 -->30
          <!-- /react-text -->
          <!-- react-text: 581 -->years
          <!-- /react-text -->
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ant-row _3jxXH">
      <div class="ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-24 ant-col-md-16"></div>
      <div class="ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-24 ant-col-md-8">
        <div class="_1A1_k"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="_3TRls _2wwQC">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please change the image as HTML snippet

Comment: Removed the image and added the html snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on HTML snippet you have shared ( Not a good idea, always share in text). I can see issue with your xPath. For div class starting with *z-k7K ant-*, you are not giving full class name but have used = operator. Instead use contains.

**Use :**

```
WebElement resultElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='calculatedresult']//div[@class='_3Kmts']//div[@class='ant-row _2kHnl']//div[contains(@class,'z-k7K ant-col-xs-24')]//p[@class='_3TRls _2fRgA']"));
```

Also I hope you dont have any issue with element load, if so use any of wait method for your element to be loaded completely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have use `explicit wait` in this case to get the text `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  WebElement resultElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='calculatedresult']//div[@class='_3Kmts']//div[@class='ant-row _2kHnl']//div[contains(@class,'z-k7K ant-col-xs-24')]//p[@class='_3TRls _2fRgA']")));
String resultText = resultElement.getText();`

Comment: Is there any other way, other than xpath to get the text from that p tag. ?

Comment: That we can only tell by seeing complete page HTML DOM. As we can use css , smaller xpath but we need to see page DOM for correct locator.

Comment: Thank you I have added the html code snippet for that section

Comment: @soccerway Thanks for sharing HTML. After seeing HTML and analyzing, i guess best bet for you is to use xpath. Reason - As you p class name is starting with _, css seletor is failing. I believe its an drawback where we can not use compound selectors. However you can write much sorter xpaths than one you are using now. Like **driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='_3TRls _2fRgA']").text**  or ***driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='calculatedresult']//p[contains(@class,'_2fRgA')]").text**